# Restriction of power balance in Pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, pyomo

I am modeling an electrical power system in pyomo for short-term unit commitment, however when creating the model in systems with a considerable number of buses the creation process takes a long time.
I have verified that the restriction of power balance by the branches implemented is the one that causes it. Any suggestions for the implementation of this restriction.

I would appreciate a lot.

In the following restriction, it is intended to calculate the power flow through the branches as the angular difference multiplied by the susceptacy and must not exceed a maximum value.

```py
def potijmax(model,l,t):
    if t == 0:
        return Constraint.Skip
    else:
        for n in model.N :
            for np in model.NP:
                if (l,n,np) in model.MAPL:
                    return (((model.D[n,t]model.D[np,t])*model.S[n,np]) )*BA <= (model.Plinemax[l])
model.Poijmax = Constraint(model.L, model.T, rule=potijmax, doc = 'Potencia maxima en la rama ij [MW]')
```

`model.D` is the angle variable

`model.S` is the susceptance parameter

`BA` is the base power

`model.N` and `model.NP` are sets of bus names

`model.L` is a set of line names

`model.T` is a set of time

`model.MAPL` is a set which contains the line names with the respective from and to buses

Comment: It seems to me this question is more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your model must be fairly large if the speed of construction is noticeable compared to the solve time.  That said, your construct above is quite inefficient, as you suspect.  You are using nested for loops to find a combination of `[l, n, np]` in a set.  This shouldn't be necessary if you already have that subset constructed.  This **assumes** your code above is intentional in that there is only one combination per instance of `l`.  I'm assuming this because you are returning the first one found.

So instead of searching for the "magic combos" that are in `model.MAPL`, just use that set as the basis of construction.  Something like the example below should work fine.

```
#constructor example

import pyomo.environ as pyo

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

###  SETS
model.N = pyo.Set(initialize=range(5))
model.NP = pyo.Set(initialize=range(5))
model.L = pyo.Set(initialize=list('ABCD'))
model.T = pyo.Set(initialize=range(5))
model.MAPL = pyo.Set(within=model.L*model.N*model.NP,
    initialize= [('B', 2, 3), ('C', 1, 4)])

###  VARS
model.X = pyo.Var(model.L, model.N, model.NP, domain=pyo.NonNegativeReals)

###  PARAMS
model.limit = pyo.Param(model.T, initialize=dict(zip(range(5), range(2,7))))  # just a dummy



### CONSTRAINTS
def C1(model, l, n, np, t):
    if t == 0:
        return pyo.Constraint.Skip
    else:
        return model.X[l, n, np] <= model.limit[t]
model.C1 = pyo.Constraint(model.MAPL, model.T, rule=C1)


model.C1.pprint()
```

#### Yields:

```
C1 : Size=8, Index=C1_index, Active=True
    Key            : Lower : Body     : Upper : Active
    ('B', 2, 3, 1) :  -Inf : X[B,2,3] :   3.0 :   True
    ('B', 2, 3, 2) :  -Inf : X[B,2,3] :   4.0 :   True
    ('B', 2, 3, 3) :  -Inf : X[B,2,3] :   5.0 :   True
    ('B', 2, 3, 4) :  -Inf : X[B,2,3] :   6.0 :   True
    ('C', 1, 4, 1) :  -Inf : X[C,1,4] :   3.0 :   True
    ('C', 1, 4, 2) :  -Inf : X[C,1,4] :   4.0 :   True
    ('C', 1, 4, 3) :  -Inf : X[C,1,4] :   5.0 :   True
    ('C', 1, 4, 4) :  -Inf : X[C,1,4] :   6.0 :   True
```